# Programmatic Retrieval of Job Information with 'workerDiskType' from Google Cloud Console

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, beam

I am attempting to retrieve the "machineType" attribute, which denotes the specific type of machine utilized within a given Google DataFlow job. Unfortunately, when making an API request using the endpoint GET [https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/{projectId}/jobs/{jobId}](https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/%7BprojectId%7D/jobs/%7BjobId%7D), the JSON response lacks the "machineType" attribute.

Interestingly, when one accesses the job information via the Google Cloud Console and navigates to the "Equivalent Rest" link at the bottom of the Job details page, it triggers a pop-up displaying a JSON structure that contains the "workerDiskType" information within the "pipelineDescription."

My inquiry pertains to the possibility of programmatically obtaining this JSON.

Comment: Have you tried to add this parameter? https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/get#query-parameters